# Get HTML-tags by namespace in PHP XPath Query

Tags: php, xml, dom, xpath

Let's say I have the following HTML snippet:

```
<div abc:section="section1">
  <p>Content...</p>
</div>
<div abc:section="section2">
  <p>Another section</p>
</div>
```

How can I get a DOMNodeList (in PHP) with a DOMNode for each of `<div>`'s with the `abc:section` attribute set.

Currently I have the following code

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html)

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$xpath->registerNamespace('abc', 'http://xml.example.com/AbcDocument');
```

Following XPath's won't work:

```
$xpath->query('//@abc:section');
$xpath->query('//*[@abc:section]');
```

The loaded HTML is always just a snippet, I'm transforming this using the DOMDocument functions and feeding that to the template.

Comment: This `//*[@abc:section]` should "work". Does the document have a default namespace?

Comment: Yeah, I would think so as well. No, I'm just loading the snippet as defined above. Haven't specified a default namespace (would be HTML), but is irrelevant I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `loadHTML` method will trigger the [HTML Parser module of libxml](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-HTMLparser.html). Afaik, the resulting HTML tree will not contain namespaces, so querying them with XPath wont work here. You can do

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHtml($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('div') as $node) {
    echo $node->getAttribute('abc:section');
}
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

As an alternative, you can use `//div/@*` to fetch all attributes and that would include the namespaced attributes. You cannot have a colon in the query though, because that requires the namespace prefix to be registered but like pointed out above, that doesnt work for an HTML tree.

Yet another alternative would be to use `//@*[starts-with(name(), "abc:section")]`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was already trying to implement your first solution. But I need to search a lot of elements of different types, in different stages, so that would be quite a lot of work to do. So'm going for your second solution, and let libxml do the work for me. (and thanks a lot for that pointer to the libxml HTML Parser, quite essential to know ;-) )

Comment: @Gordon: I don't think is a good idea to encourage the missuse of namespaces.

Comment: @Alejandro if you know a solution to solve that problem with the proper Xpath, feel free to add. I dont think it's possible with the given setup. And in that sense, it's not misusing namespaces, because technically there is no namespaces in the HTML tree at all. It's Tag Soup.

Comment: @Gordon: I agree. But then one should not be using XPath. I think your first answer it's the right answer using DOM methods.

Comment: Yeah, I know the first method is better, and I also know HTML doesn't work with namespaces, because it's not an XML (well-formed) document. 
But I got my solution working 'for now', and in the near future I have to do a lot more with the DOMDocument (more transformations), and then I'll look into to the first 'looping through the nodes' method. Maybe I can create my own wrapper class, which takes of it for me. Also thank you for your input Alejandro.

Comment: Just to let you know. I dropped namespaces all together. Just "invented" my own tags with their own attributes. Also found some PHP class which lets me query the DOMDocument with JQuery style selectors. Thanks again for your input.